# Definition of $f$-invariant in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I'm studying linear algebra for math undergrad students, yet I have no background in maths, so I was wondering what the highlighted part of the text means. I tried to "google" it yet I did not find a way to discover its meaning.

[image]

Comment: It's explained just after: if $x \in W$, then $f(x) \in W$.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I think I should stop studying for today. Thank you :)

Comment: No worries. If this answers your question, I'll post it as an answer!

Comment: yeah it anwsers my question. I'll approve it when you post it. Sorry again for taking your time :(

Comment: Not at all, we all miss things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's explained just after: if $x \in W$, then $f(x) \in W$.